# Tiny MCE v5.10.2 adds <br> tag in empty DIV tags

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

[image]I am trying to display some html in the Tiny MCE editor v5.10.2.

My HTML has some blank DIVs with our custom classes. However on setting the content on Editor, tinymce add 
 inside those empty divs. I have tried almost all config settings, but none of them has worked. This is very critical for me as I am migrating from Medium Editor to Tinymce, so already have tonnes of such templates which cannot be changed. I have attached an image explaining the same.

[image]

Comment: I have added one more image to explain the problem at hand. The issue with BR tags is that its changing the design of the already existing html templates. The visualization also changes. I have attached a screen shot comparing our existing component with Tiny MCE and highlighting the issue at hand. So if by any config changes I can skip this changing of DOM elements, it will work for us.

Comment: same here, no solution?